an elementalist manga where female lead goes to past
I don't remember the name of the manga, but the female lead travels back in time. In her past life, she was sacrificed for her brother because she didn't manifest water powers. After traveling back in time, she develops incredibly strong water magic and forms a pact with the Spirit King. She also helps cure the male lead's curse, which made him blind.
